# increase file size for log files from scripts started from postfix

Tags: postfix, perl

I am using Postfix to run a script whenever a message is sent to a specific address.  The script is a Perl script and it writes a log to a file using [Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.46/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm).  The log file is being rotated on a daily basis by Log4perl.

It's working well except for one small corner case.  The script is not able to write to the log file when the log's file size is above 50MB.

After doing some research on Postfix, it appears that this may be a limitation set from Postfix.  Here is part of the output from `postconf` that may be relevant.

```
$ postconf | grep size
berkeley_db_create_buffer_size = 16777216
berkeley_db_read_buffer_size = 131072
body_checks_size_limit = 51200
bounce_size_limit = 50000
header_size_limit = 102400
mailbox_size_limit = 51200000
message_size_limit = 10240000
tcp_windowsize = 0

$ postconf | grep virtual_mailbox_limit
virtual_mailbox_limit = 51200000
```

Are there any options that could be changed to **remove the 50MB limit for the file size of the log file** created from the script?

Here are the Log4perl settings for completeness.

```
$ cat /some/path/to/my/log4perlsettings.cfg
log4perl.logger.mylog = DEBUG,LOGGER
log4perl.appender.LOGGER = Log::Dispatch::FileRotate
log4perl.appender.LOGGER.TZ=PST
log4perl.appender.LOGGER.DatePattern=yyyy-MM-dd
log4perl.appender.LOGGER.filename = /some/path/to/my/logs/logfile.log
log4perl.appender.LOGGER.mode = append
log4perl.appender.LOGGER.max = 30
log4perl.appender.LOGGER.layout = PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.LOGGER.layout.ConversionPattern = [%d] %P %p %r %H %F %L %C - %m%n
```

These probably aren't relevant, but here are the Postfix alias settings:

```
$ grep -r myscript /etc/postfix/
/etc/postfix/virtual:myscript@mymachine.example.net        myscript

$ grep -r myscript /etc/aliases
myscript:       "|/some/path/to/my/script.pl"
```

***Edit***:

Here is the output from `/var/log/maillog`.  This repeats many, many times.

```
Dec 13 10:59:22 mymachine postfix/cleanup[22052]: EB5EA80196: message-id=<20141213015922.EB5EA80196@mymachine.example.net>
Dec 13 10:59:22 mymachine postfix/bounce[22431]: 7C11080190: sender non-delivery notification: EB5EA80196
Dec 13 10:59:22 mymachine postfix/qmgr[2109]: EB5EA80196: from=<>, size=3456, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 13 10:59:22 mymachine postfix/qmgr[2109]: 7C11080190: removed
Dec 13 10:59:23 mymachine postfix/smtp[22342]: EB5EA80196: to=<root@othermachine.example.net>, relay=mail.example.net[192.168.1.11]:25, delay=0.04, delays=0.01/0/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok 1418435963 qp 19340)
Dec 13 10:59:23 mymachine postfix/qmgr[2109]: EB5EA80196: removed
Dec 13 10:59:39 mymachine postfix/smtpd[21267]: connect from unknown[192.168.2.12]
Dec 13 10:59:39 mymachine postfix/smtpd[21267]: CA0AB80190: client=unknown[192.168.2.12]
Dec 13 10:59:39 mymachine postfix/cleanup[21893]: CA0AB80190: message-id=<20141213015939.B625B1228002@othermachine2.example.net>
Dec 13 10:59:39 mymachine postfix/smtpd[21267]: disconnect from unknown[192.168.2.12]
Dec 13 10:59:39 mymachine postfix/qmgr[2109]: CA0AB80190: from=<root@othermachine2.net>, size=712, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 13 10:59:40 mymachine postfix/local[21269]: CA0AB80190: to=<myscript@mymachine.example.net>, relay=local, delay=0.43, delays=0.02/0/0/0.4, dsn=5.3.0, status=bounced (Command died with status 27: "/some/path/to/my/script.pl". Command output: Cannot write to '/some/path/to/my/logs/logfile.log': File too large at /usr/local/share/perl5/Log/Dispatch/File.pm line 141. )
Dec 13 10:59:40 mymachine postfix/cleanup[22052]: 3B8FD80196: message-id=<20141213015940.3B8FD80196@mymachine.example.net>
Dec 13 10:59:40 mymachine postfix/bounce[22431]: CA0AB80190: sender non-delivery notification: 3B8FD80196
Dec 13 10:59:40 mymachine postfix/qmgr[2109]: 3B8FD80196: from=<>, size=2897, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 13 10:59:40 mymachine postfix/qmgr[2109]: CA0AB80190: removed
Dec 13 10:59:40 mymachine postfix/smtp[21679]: 3B8FD80196: to=<root@othermachine2.example.net>, relay=mail.example.net[192.168.1.11]:25, delay=0.04, delays=0/0/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok 1418435980 qp 19356)
Dec 13 10:59:40 mymachine postfix/qmgr[2109]: 3B8FD80196: removed
```

The important line is probably this one:

```
Dec 13 10:59:40 mymachine postfix/local[21269]: CA0AB80190: to=<myscript@mymachine.example.net>, relay=local, delay=0.43, delays=0.02/0/0/0.4, dsn=5.3.0, status=bounced (Command died with status 27: "/some/path/to/my/script.pl". Command output: Cannot write to '/some/path/to/my/logs/logfile.log': File too large at /usr/local/share/perl5/Log/Dispatch/File.pm line 141. )
```

This error starts occuring exactly when `/some/path/to/my/logs/logfile.log`'s filesize is 50MB (51200000 bytes).

***Edit2***:

The perl script runs correctly when being called from the command line (i.e. without being called from Postfix).

Comment: I have added the error message in an edit.

Comment: The 50MB limitation appears to be from Postfix.  At least, it matches up exactly with the `mailbox_size_limit` and `virtual_mailbox_limit` settings from Postfix.  I was thinking that Postfix sets these limits and they are inherited in the script which is inherited by the Postfix process.

Comment: It doesn't look like the Log4perl module imposes any sort of 50MB limitation on the size of log files.

Comment: can you run the perl script without postfix (invoke via terminal)?

Comment: The perl script runs correctly when being called via the terminal, even when writing to a 50MB file.

Comment: @masegaloeh Please don't advise people to delete their question and ask again. If the question is inappropriate here but would be appropriate elsewhere, flag it so that it can be moved automatically instead. Also, in this case, since the question is about the intersection between postfix and perl, [unix.se] would be more appropriate than [so].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed a limitation inherited from postfix. The reason is that when you're writing to a script by directing deliveries to a pipe, then that counts as a mailbox, just as if you'd written directly to a file. So whatever limits are set on the postfix delivery agent will be inherited by the script.

I can think of three ways to get around this:

1. You change the limitations in your postfix configuration; you've already pinpointed the source of the limitation.
2. You run logrotate more often, so that the file doesn't get above 50 MB.
3. You change your script to use the logrotate functions available in [Log::Dispatch::FileRotate](http://search.cpan.org/~markpf/Log-Dispatch-FileRotate-1.19/FileRotate.pm), so that the file will automagically be rotated when it exceeds 50 MB.

Comment: For solution 1, which one of `mailbox_size_limit` or `virtual_mailbox_limit` needs to be adjusted?  From a quick skim of the docs, it doesn't seem clear whether directing deliveries to a pipe will use `mailbox_size_limit` or `virtual_mailbox_limit`.

Comment: It looks like you're using the `alias` mechanism to deliver the mail? If so, then it should be `mailbox_size_limit`.